# Serialize ImageSource in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, serialization, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to serialize a class with a member being the `ImageSource` type.
The class being:

```
    public class AppInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ImageSource Icon { get; set; }
        public bool Is90Hz { get; set; }
    }
```

I get the data for the class like this:

```
        private static IList<AppInfo> GetAppInfos()
        {
            var localAppInfo = new List<AppInfo>();
            var allAppsRaw = DependencyService.Get<IGetAllApps>().GetApps();

            var pm = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager;
            if (pm == null)
                return null;

            foreach (var info in allAppsRaw)
            {
                var bitmap = DependencyService.Get<IGetAllApps>().DrawableToBitmap(info.LoadIcon(pm));
                byte[] bitmapData;

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                    bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                }

                var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.Length));

                localAppInfo.Add(new AppInfo { Name = info.LoadLabel(pm), Icon = imageSource, Is90Hz = true });
            }

            return localAppInfo;
        }
```

The problem is that System.Text.Json can't serialize that type. I searched back and forth on how I could convert it to a byte array or a Base64 string but I'm kinda lost.

I added `[JsonConverter(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]` to the member and declared my converter class as follows:

```
    public class ImageSourceConverter : JsonConverter<ImageSource>
    {
        public override ImageSource Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ImageSource value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
        }
    }
```

But I'm kinda lost at this point... Just can't figure out the logic for the read and write methods.

*Edit:
The end goal is to display it, current way of doing it:

```
        <ListView Grid.Column="3" x:Name="AppsView" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="true">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon, Mode=TwoWay}" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Is90Hz, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way to do this.  ImageSource is not designed to expose it's underlying data.  You would be better off storing a file path, url or byte[] in your AppInfo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I ended up doing something similar with a converter.
In my xaml:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
              <api:ByteArrayToImageConverter x:Key="Bti"/>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
<Image Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource Bti}, Mode=Default}" WidthRequest="37" HeightRequest="37" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
```

The converter class:

```
    public class ByteArrayToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            var imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
            return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) =>
                throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

And I just save the photo as a `byte[]`
:

```
                var bitmap = DependencyService.Get<IGetAllApps>().DrawableToBitmap(info.LoadIcon(pm));
                byte[] bitmapData;

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                    bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                }

                localAppInfo.Add(new AppInfo
                    {Name = info.LoadLabel(pm), PackageName = info.PackageName, Icon = bitmapData, Is90Hz = true});
```

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms uses the **Image** view to display images on a page. It has several important properties:

**Source** - An ImageSource instance, either File, Uri or Resource, which sets the image to display.

**ImageSource** instances can be obtained using static methods for each type of image source:

- `FromFile` - Requires a filename or filepath that can be resolved on each platform.
- `FromUri` - Requires a Uri object, eg. new Uri("http://....") .
- `FromResource` - Requires a resource identifier to an image file embedded in the application or .NET Standard library project, with a
  Build Action:EmbeddedResource.
- `FromStream` - Requires a stream that supplies image data.

So you could try to binding the stream :

change

```
public ImageSource Icon { get; set; }
```

to

```
public Stream Icon { get; set; }
```

then add the stream:

```
var imageSource = new MemoryStream(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.Length);

localAppInfo.Add(new AppInfo { Name = info.LoadLabel(pm), Icon = imageSource, Is90Hz = true });
```

in your xaml:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
       <StreamImageSource Stream="{Binding Icon}"
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```